# Ocaml utop library paths, Core module

Tags: ocaml

I am attempting to use the `Core` module in `utop`, as originated by Jane Street and installed using `opam`.

Here's the problem

```
utop # open Core.Std;;
Error: Unbound module Core
```

`utop` does not seem to have the path to the `Core` module.

How do you specify a path that can be found by `utop` to access the `Core` module? Is there a `utop` init file that specifies library paths ?

I have the same error message from the OCaml 4.01.0 interpreter.

The only way I can avoid this error is actually changing directory to `/Users/myname/.opam/system/lib/core`.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem, the directions here got it working for me.

https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions#setting-up-and-using-utop

add the following lines to your  ~/.ocamlinit file

```
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
```

Answer (score 13):

Assuming that you have core properly installed through opam:

```
# require "core";;
open Core.Std;;
```

Should work.