# How do you install OCaml with Jane Street's Core using OPAM?

Tags: opam, ocaml-core

The simple directions found all over the internet for installing Core using OPAM no longer work. What is the new way to install and use Core?

I think I tracked the problem down to a message on the ocaml-core mailing list about renaming several dependencies https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ocaml-core/Te6LTiNBO08.

Paired down, the widely published installation instructions amount to two steps after installing opam itself:

```
$ opam install core

$ cat >> ~/.ocamlinit <<EOF
#use "topfind";;
#thread;;
#camlp4o;;
#require "core.top";;
#require "core.syntax";;
EOF
```

Following these directions result in an error about the "sexprlib.syntax" package missing when using `ocaml` (or `corebuild`, `utop`, etc).

Failing directions can be found in this widely referenced ebook
https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions#setting-up-and-using-utop
and are reflected in directions here on Stackoverflow in questions such as:
[Ocaml utop library paths, Core module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20927592/ocaml-utop-library-paths-core-module)

What is the new way to set up Core?

`opam install core` no longer seems to be sufficient since it does not pull in the new syntax packages. I am not sure if this is a dependency bug or not.
The recommended ocamlinit settings also seem wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the core 113.24.00 is defective and all the installation instructions on the net as of this writing are out of date.

Users must make the following corrective steps:

- Remove all `#require` references to packages ending in `.syntax` from `~/.ocamlinit`.
- Make your own `corebuild` script without any references to syntax packages
  as found at https://github.com/janestreet/core/blob/master/corebuild.

You may also remove the `#camlp4o;;` line from your `.ocamlinit` as this library is no longer required by Core.